# How can I hash an input into an arbitrary domain point?

Tags: hash, signature, sha-256, padding, random-oracle-model

I am trying to implement a signature scheme involving *RSA* signing of a message digest generated by SHA-$256$. I want to hash the input into an *RSA* domain point instead of the fixed *$256$* bit digest generated by *SHA*. 

Apparently, this can be achieved using a Full Domain Hashing

From the Wikipedia definition of [Full Domain Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_Domain_Hash)

> In cryptography, the Full Domain Hash (*FDH*) is an *RSA*-based signature scheme that follows the *hash-and-sign* paradigm. It is provably secure (i.e., is existentially unforgeable under adaptive chosen-message attacks) in the random oracle model. *FDH* involves hashing a message using a function whose image size equals the size of the *RSA* modulus, and then raising the result to the secret *RSA* exponent.

How would one go about practically implementing the following part of the *FDH* process:

> hashing a message using a function whose image size equals the size of the RSA modulus

I have tried randomly padding the *$256$* bit digest, however, it requires sending extra values to remove the padding before verification.
I also looked at some papers on [Random Oracles and FDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_oracle) by Bellare and Rogaway([Paper 1](https://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2000/18800229/18800229.pdf),[Paper 2](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/ro.pdf)) which are a little to esoteric for me and as  such, I'm looking for simplified explanation of the process.

Comment: Does the RSA-PSS is not enough for you?

Comment: "provably secure in the random oracle model"... I thought the random oracle model had fallen out of favor. Isn't the random sponge model the preferred model for analyzing protocols based on hash functions nowadays?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hash functions we use, e.g. Sha-1, Sha-256, Sha-512, usually don’t have a sufficiently large range. But we can construct full domain hash via repeated application of a hash function $h$: $FDH(m) = h(m||0)||h(m||1)||\cdots  $, then take the leading n-bit. This way the hash value is deterministic and the size is arbitrary.

This is something like MGF1 defined in [PKCS #1 v2.2](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr), B.2.1.

Comment: Thank you. This technique seems to be working perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use an eXtendible Output Function (XOF) for that ?

For example, SHAKE-128, defined in the [SHA-3 standard](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.202.pdf), allows you to hash a message and obtain as output as many bits as you want. This is flexible so that it can be easily adapted to the size of your RSA modulus.

Comment: While that would address the problem I have, I would like a method of extending the hash output based on any simpler hash function (SHA256) in my case.